# Is the Waves smart contract has similar addresses as in Ethereum?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, smartcontracts, wavesplatform, ride

Does Waves smart contracts have addresses similar to the Ethereum one's '0xef3fbc3e228dbdc523ce5e58530874005553eb2e’?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be more precise, there are smart accounts in Waves and they have addresses, like usual Waves address, but you can't call them by the address. I think you can better understand how smart accounts and assets work from [the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FEq4kU9mAas&t=1s)

Answer (score 1):

No [Waves smart contracts](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/smart-contracts/waves-contracts-language-description.html) does not have numbers similar to Ethereum because smart contracts in Waves have [scripts](https://docs.wavesplatform.com/en/smart-contracts/smart-accounts.html) which are attached to accounts.